# PHP - Getting the class, which has called method

Tags: php, oop

I would like to generate an log file. Therefor I have created a static class called log with an method called write:

```
class log {  
public static function write($info) {  
// file writing  
}
}
```

In this function i would like to know from which class the method write is called (automatically):

```
log::write("Testinformation");
```

I have already tried with: get_called_class - but this gives me only "log" instead of the "real" called class...

Is there any way to automatically retrieve the called class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$offset = 1;
$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
$caller = array();
if(isset($backtrace[$offset])) {
    $backtrace = $backtrace[$offset];
    if(isset($backtrace['class'])) {
        $caller['class'] = $backtrace['class'];
    }
    if(isset($backtrace['function'])) {
        $caller['function'] = $backtrace['function'];
    }

}
```

No you have info about calling class and method or function. You can also use function I wrote long time ago

```
<?php
function getCaller($offset = 0) {
    $baseOffset = 2;
    $offset += $baseOffset;
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $caller = array();
    if(isset($backtrace[$offset])) {
        $backtrace = $backtrace[$offset];
        if(isset($backtrace['class'])) {
            $caller['class'] = $backtrace['class'];
        }
        if(isset($backtrace['function'])) {
            $caller['function'] = $backtrace['function'];
        }

    }
    return $caller;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve the class that called it.

use something like:

```
define("log_tag", "myclass")
```

at the start of the file, and through out the rest of the file call:

```
log::write(log_tag, "testinformation");`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to add the class name at the call of the method :

```
class Foo 
{
    public function bar()
    {
        // do something ... 
        log::write(get_called_class().': blablabla...');
    }
}
```